# NodeJS AMQP Client can't connect

Tags: php, node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

I am going crazy for last two days, i cannot make connection on NodeJS client with durable exchange and durable queue.

So PHP code creates and send message:

```
<?php 
$connection = new AMQPConnection(array(
'host' => 'localhost',
'vhost' => 'bvh',
'port' => 5672,
'login' => 'bizneus',
'password' => 'lozinkus'
));
    //$connection = new AMQPConnection();
    $connection->connect();
    if (!$connection->isConnected()) {
        die('Not connected :(' . PHP_EOL);
    }
    // Open Channel
    $channel    = new AMQPChannel($connection);
    // Declare exchange
    $exchange   = new AMQPExchange($channel);
    $exchange->setName('biznea_e_1');       
    $exchange->setType('fanout');
    $exchange->setFlags(AMQP_DURABLE);

    $exchange->declare();
    // Create Queue
    $queue      = new AMQPQueue($channel);
    $queue->setName('notify');
    $queue->setFlags(AMQP_DURABLE);
    $queue->declare();

    $message    = $exchange->publish(json_encode($s), 'kljuc');
    if (!$message) {
        echo 'Message not sent', PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo 'Message sent!', PHP_EOL;
    }

    if ($connection->isConnected()) {
       $connection->disconnect();
    }
```

On screen it says that messege is sent.

Next thing is NodeJS client, which should get messages, but it can't:

```
var amqp = require('amqp');

var conParam = { 
  host: 'localhost', 
  port: 5672,  
  login: 'bizneus',   
  password: 'lozinkus',    
  vhost: 'bvh'  
}
var connection = amqp.createConnection(conParam);
connection.on('ready', function(){

     var exchange = connection.exchange('biznea_e_1');
      var queue = connection.queue('notify');
      queue.bind('biznea_e_1', 'kljuc');

                queue.subscribe( {ack:true}, function(message){

                    var dj = JSON.parse(message.data.toString());

                    console.log(JSON.stringify(dj));

                    queue.shift();
            });
});
```

but I get this error

```
events.js:66
        throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                       ^
Error: PRECONDITION_FAILED - cannot redeclare exchange 'biznea_e_1' in vhost 'bvh' with different type, durable, internal or autodelete value
    at Exchange._onMethod (/home/zijad/node_modules/amqp/amqp.js:1824:15)
    at Exchange.Channel._onChannelMethod (/home/zijad/node_modules/amqp/amqp.js:1365:14)
    at Connection._onMethod (/home/zijad/node_modules/amqp/amqp.js:922:28)
    at AMQPParser.self.addListener.parser.onMethod (/home/zijad/node_modules/amqp/amqp.js:797:12)
    at AMQPParser._parseMethodFrame (/home/zijad/node_modules/amqp/amqp.js:442:10)
    at frameEnd (/home/zijad/node_modules/amqp/amqp.js:187:16)
    at frame (/home/zijad/node_modules/amqp/amqp.js:172:14)
    at AMQPParser.header [as parse] (/home/zijad/node_modules/amqp/amqp.js:159:14)
    at AMQPParser.execute (/home/zijad/node_modules/amqp/amqp.js:231:21)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/home/zijad/node_modules/amqp/amqp.js:837:12)
```

I tried to remove var exchange = connection.exchange('biznea_e_1'); that line but than it cannot declare queue.

I just want to send messages from PHP to NodeJS deamon and that is all!

Help :)

Comment: I quit using this method and start using Redis instead of AMQP, it is easier in few minutes everything was installed and runing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: In the node.js code, declare the exchanges and queues with *EXACTLY* the same parameters as you did in your PHP code. e.g. durable. This may solve your problem.

Cheers!

Comment: How to setup these parameters for node?

Comment: Did you look at the node-amqp documentation for the functions you are using? Its probably all there. Look at the docs for connection.exchange, connection.queue etc.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to create the exchange 'biznea_e_1' again in the node.js code. It is already created by the php code. Try only to subscribe.