# How to connect PHP producer with NodeJS consumer via RabbitMQ (amqp)?

Tags: php, node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

I tried a lot of ways to do this bud without any good progress. So I have installed amqp extension for php via pecl, amqp and rabbit.js for nodejs, and rabbitmq-server, everything is working individually :)

Scenario is:
PHP -> send message to RabbitMQ -> NodeJS consumer (deamon) -> recive message

Comment: so....where is the problem? what have you tried? where is the code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096735/nodejs-amqp-client-cant-connect/12124398#comment16249575_12124398